# How to frame accurately cut a video with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I have a video. Here is it's `ffprobe` output:

```
> ffprobe 7347-00009\ kliksa.mp4
ffprobe version 2.6.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.6.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-libquvi --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '7347-00009 kliksa.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: avc1isommp42
    creation_time   : 2015-09-17 14:04:14
  Duration: 00:00:30.44, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7238 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 6977 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-17 14:04:14
      handler_name    : ?Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : inegy Cinecoder H.264 Encoder
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 255 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-17 14:04:14
      handler_name    : ?Apple Sound Media Handler
```

All players show that it's duration is 30 seconds. But it's EXACT duration is `00:00:30.44` as `ffprobe` shows.

What I want to do is setting the videos duration to EXACTLY `00:00:30.00`.

I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -i 7347-00009\ kliksa.mp4 -c copy -ss 00:00:00.000 -to 30.000 test.mp4
```

But I still have a duration of `00:00:30.02`. Here is ffprobe output:

```
> ffprobe test.mp4
ffprobe version 2.6.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.6.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-libquvi --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
  Duration: 00:00:30.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7240 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 6982 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 255 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

So, how can I have a video cut frame accurately?

Comment: Isn't it weird that no one knows how to do it? :\

Comment: I tried to replicate your results (a different duration than specified) and had a bit of difficulty there- all the videos `ffmpeg` was producing for me were of the exact duration I asked for. When i did replicate it I thought it might be due to bitstream copying but re-encoding actually made the problem *worse*. I suspect it may be down to a nuance of `libx264`, but that's just speculation. You may get a response [on the `ffmpeg-user` mailing list](https://www.ffmpeg.org/contact.html), however.

Comment: I think the problem is caused by the stream copy command. It may not be able to cut in the middle of ref frames. Try with -vcodec libx264 as a test.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://superuser.com/a/1021065/180380) answer, frame-accurate cutting of video using `ffmpeg` without re-encoding is only possible at GOP boundaries. I am not sure if it applies to cutting just the end of a video or not.

BTW, a constant frame rate video at 25 fps cannot have a duration of 30.02 seconds. 1 frame is supposed to be on display for 1/25 of a second, which is 0.04 seconds.

Maybe your video just has bad timestamps? Try regenerating them:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -fflags +genpts output.mp4
```