# Frame accurate video cut using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I want to use ffmpeg to cut a video file at some exact frame.

Let's take [this video](https://download.blender.org/durian/trailer/sintel_trailer-1080p.mp4). First, I get a frame at 25 second:

```
ffmpeg -i sintel_trailer-1080p.mp4 -ss 25 -vframes 1 25.png
```

Note that I use postfix `-ss` option, so seeking must be frame accurate.
Here's my image:

[image]

Then I cut the video at 25 second using stream copy and check its first frame:

```
ffmpeg -i sintel_trailer-1080p.mp4 -ss 25 -c copy cut.mp4
ffmpeg -i cut.mp4 -vframes 1 0.png
```

The first frame is different:

[image]

But if I replace stream copy option with some other format or video codec, the first frame is correct:

```
ffmpeg -i sintel_trailer-1080p.mp4 -ss 25 -f avi cut.avi
ffmpeg -i cut.avi -vframes 1 0_1.png
```

[image]

Is it possible at all to get frame accurate seeking with stream copy mode?

In my application user should be able to pick a frame and start a process that will cut video exactly at that frame. In this case I don't need any video conversion but at the same time I can't make stream copy mode to be frame accurate.

Comment: Unless the video stream is intra-coded , not [possible](http://superuser.com/a/1021065/114058).

Comment: How can I tell that the video is intra-coded?